# Minimal step response overshoot IIR notch filter design

Tags: filters, filter-design

Is there any IIR notch filter design algorithm, strategy or rule of thumb, that provides control for amount of overshoot/undershoot in step response of a filter?

Comment: if the notch is 2nd-order, a biquad, i am sure that someone somewhere has worked out explicit closed-form expressions of the impulse response and the step response.  from that you can derive overshoot.

Comment: [Here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/9177/4298) are some formulas for a biquad filter. I don't know of any design algorithm that imposes limits on overshoot/undershoot for the IIR case. You would need a non-linear optimization algorithm and you would have to deal with the problem of locally (but not globally) optimal solutions.

Comment: wew!  "$\sigma(n)$" for the Heaviside step function?  that's a little unconventional, no?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Greek sigma for "S" for "step" ... variatio delectat.

Comment: @MattL. Could you, please, provide a reference for the equation (1) from the answer (equation for a(n))?

Comment: @0xff: I don't think I can, I think I just derived it myself back then. It's pretty straightforward, albeit a bit tedious. I might add the derivation as an answer to this question if I find the time to do so.

Comment: @MattL. Ok. Got it. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction!  I'm on my way to do it. Anyway, your comment was very helpful!

Comment: @0xff: Let me know if you're having trouble coming up with that expression.